# How to Setup Jetpack Navigation with material.BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, navigation, android-studio-3.0, android-jetpack

I am unable to setup Navigation component with **com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView** it is giving an error.

[image]

Here is the code that I am trying to use

```
 // Setup bottom navigation view
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
            bottom_navigation_view,
            findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
    )
```

when I open the **NavigationUI** class, I note that it just accept the old **android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView** but I want to use the new one **com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView** class. Any idea about it?

**[Update 14/11/2019]**

This was a bug and was fixed at Android Gradle Plugin (~3.2.0-rc-01 and 3.3.0-alpha-04). You can see the issue tracker in the following link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110692942

Answer (score 6):

I am using these libraries

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
// Architecture Components
def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
// use -ktx for Kotlin
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

and this is my Activity

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavView, 
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment))
```

and this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.main.ActivityMain">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_16"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: for me its still not working. it only takes to homepage, when i click on other tabs, it does not take there.

Answer (score 1):

Please update "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha03" for solve this problem

[NavigationUI updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0XHN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Navigation documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#navigation as of June 29th 2018.

It says:

> Blockquote
>   Navigation classes are already in the androidx.navigation package, but currently depend on Support Library 27.1.1, and associated Arch component versions. Version of Navigation with AndroidX dependencies will be released in the future.

I guess for now you have no choice but waiting for a "future" release of the Navigation package.

For the time being, as suggested by @Levi Albuquerque, you need to use `com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3`.
It should work the same way `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3` does.