# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView & Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview, material-components, material-components-android

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

gradle source

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

layout xml source

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottomnavigationview">  
 </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

what am I missing? 
does androidstuido still support `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView"`?

Comment: I think you should check the `@menu/menu_bottomnavigationview` menu. To check it you try to remove `app:menu="@menu/menu_bottomnavigationview"`(if you can). And re-run the app.

Comment: @thrillingchase - it sounds like the problem was a missing/conflicting dependency, caused by "android.support" vs. "androidx" Gradle dependencies and/or Java packages.  Perhaps all you needed to do was change the package name in your XML layout.  Q: Is your problem "resolved"?

Answer (score 3):

The class `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` is provided by the [design support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#design).
It requires the `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` dependency.

You are using **androidx** libraries.
In this case you have to use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

It requires the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

and the component is [**`com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigationView.md)

Comment: Good catch: I didn't notice the "androidx" dependency!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

and

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
...
>
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView), it's

- added in version 26.1.0
- belongs to Maven artifact com.android.support:design:27.1.0

Unfortunately, this documentation is for the (old) android.support libraries.  This thread discusses how to use BottomNavigationView with the (new) androidx libraries:

[How to Setup Jetpack Navigation with material.BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005730/how-to-setup-jetpack-navigation-with-material-bottomnavigationview)

As both Gabriele Mariotti and RavenYang said, if you're using androidx, you need to:

- Specify `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10` in your build.gradle

  ... **AND ** ...
- Specify the androidx package `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` in your layout XML.

EXAMPLE (android.support):

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   ...
```

EXAMPLE (androidx):

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10' 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **androidx** libraries.
so you have to use

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added more than 5 items on the menu which caused the crash. After adding only 5 items in the menu I stopped seeing this crash.